# How to deploy an ASP.net C# on windows2008 server

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, deployment, setup-deployment

I want to deploy a Website which i have created using Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Express Edition onto a remote server having Microsoft Windows Server 2008.

I don't know anything about deployment. I want to know what are the things required on the Server in order to make the website work for all the client machines.

i had used ajax toolkit, VisualStudio2008 Express Edition and mysql on my developer machine.

One method which i tried is using copy website,it dint work,may be because i don't know the proper way to do it.

Please help me to deploy my ASP.net website.

Comment: Is this server going to act just as a web server? Or an all in one kind of server?

Comment: just as web server,what does all in one kind mean??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first step to setup your website on Windows Server 2008.  Is to setup IIS.  [Installing IIS7 on Windows Server 2008.](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/29/installing-iis-7-on-windows-server-2008-or-windows-server-2008-r2/)

Once that's completed, setup your SQL server on either that machine or a different one.

Depending on your setup.  Copy your website files to your web site directory.  By default it's [Drive]:\inetpub\wwwroot.  You can change the target by virtual directories.

One note, you will need to install AJAX on your server for it to run correctly.

Comment: thank you very much, I have developed the application using Visual Studio 2008 express edition. Will my website work properly?

Comment: You should have no problem running a website developed in Visual Studio 2008 Express.  I have one running from Visual Studio 2010 Express.  Just make sure you have the proper software installed on your server.  Ex: .NET Framework, AJAX, etc...